# Header control in WinForms - any such thing?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to use the windows native (Theme-aware) header control to display just some column headers. The main purpose is to avoid manually drawing the column headers and rely on the natively supported functionality.

So the 2 options I was thinking of are:

1. Use a `HeaderControl`, and add columns to it (I can't seem to find a header control supported by WinForms).
2. Use a `ListView` control, and tell it display no rows (or basically set its height to the height of the column header) - can't find any way to determine which height should I assign to the control.

Any good ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `HeaderControl` for WinForms in the .NET framework so far (the `ListView` utilises the `ColumnHeader` class but this is only useful with the `ListView`). If you are only targetting Microsoft Windows, you could look at wrapping the Win32 control for use in .NET although I expect that will be substantial work.

Your second option is a valid possibility even though it feels somewhat clunky. I can see difficulties arising in getting the list to size properly such that the header and only the header is visible.

A third option would be to roll your own `HeaderButton` that represents one column (like `ColumnHeader`) and use the theme drawing calls to draw it, then just combine them in a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` into your header bar. If you want resizing, you could make the `HeaderButton` have a grab region that you can pick up and alter its width.

I think the third option will be reasonably simple to create, even with the sizing ability, so I would recommend taking that route (I might even give it a go myself when I get home tonight).